# Error : a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Tags: python

I am trying this, and it shows error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-085dfa8fff25> in <module>
----> 1 s.send(text)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

My approach so far:

```
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("www.python.org",80))
s.send("GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n")
chunks = []
while True:
        chunk = s.recv(16384)
        if not chunk: break
        chunks.append(chunk)
s.close()
response = "".join(chunks)
print (response)
```

What is causing this error, and how can i resolve it?

Comment: there is a problem in line no. 4

Comment: does `b"GET /index.html HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n"` work ?

Comment: work well can u explain what does line 4 means